# Why are Child View Controller's View and subviews not resizing?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using `xib` files.

I have a `viewController` I am adding programmatically to my home screen on an iPad as a sidebar.

In Interface Builder I am setting height as flexible and left-margin,top-margin,and bottom-margin as fixed for the `childViewController`.

I have given similar config for `subviews` of this `view`.

So basically when the parent view controller rotates to portrait or landscape `childViewController` should remain exactly as it is.
Only its height should increase which is actually not happening.

I have added its view as a `subview` as well as added it as  a `childViewController`.
This is the function that gets called when I have to bring the `childViewController`.

```
-(void)showSetNewPasswordScreen
{
    BOASetNewPasswordViewController *passwordSetterScreen = [[BOASetNewPasswordViewController alloc]     initWithNibName:@"BOASetNewPasswordViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self addChildViewController:passwordSetterScreen];
    [self.view addSubview:passwordSetterScreen.view];
    CGRect frame = passwordSetterScreen.view.frame;
    frame.origin =  self.loginView.frame.origin;
    passwordSetterScreen.view.frame = frame;
    passwordSetterScreen.delegate = self;
    self.setNewPasswordViewController = passwordSetterScreen;
    [passwordSetterScreen release];
}
```

**UPDATE:** I am not using autolayouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to comment these lines :

```
CGRect frame = passwordSetterScreen.view.frame;
frame.origin =  self.loginView.frame.origin;
passwordSetterScreen.view.frame = frame;
```

Comment: It was a logical error.
I didn't set the height properly and only set the origin.

Answer (score 1):

in xib reset the auto layout option for the xib options in the right side.

Comment: I am not using autolayouts